# Letter Avatar - How to add different color classes for each set of alphabets - A to H, J to S, T to Z?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add color classes - badge-green, badge-gold, badge-blue to each set of alphabets - A to H, J to S, T to Z respectively for my letter avatar (Like in Gmail).
[View code here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoeLap)

```
var firstName = $('.firstName').text();
    var nameIntials = $('.firstName').text().charAt(0) /*+ $('#lastName').text().charAt(0)*/;
    $('.profileImage').each(function(){
        var profileImage = $(this).siblings('.firstName').text().charAt(0);
        $(this).text( profileImage );        
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voila

```js
var firstName = $('.firstName').text();
    var nameIntials = $('.firstName').text().charAt(0) /*+ $('#lastName').text().charAt(0)*/;
    $('.profileImage').each(function(){
        var profileInitial = $(this).siblings('.firstName').text().charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        $(this).text( profileInitial );
        var avatarClass = profileInitial <= "H" ? "badge-green" : (profileInitial <= "S" ? "badge-gold" : "badge-blue");
        $(this).addClass(avatarClass);
    });
```

```css
.badge-avatar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: initial;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px;
    font-weight: 400;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.badge-green {
    color: #52c41a;
    background: #f6ffed;
    border-color: #b7eb8f;
}

.badge-gold {
    color: #faad14;
    background: #fffbe6;
    border-color: #ffe58f;
}

.badge-blue {
    color: #1890ff;
    background: #e6f7ff;
    border-color: #91d5ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="profileImage badge-avatar badge-green"></span>
      <span class="firstName">Hannah</span>
    </td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>female</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="profileImage badge-avatar badge-green"></span>
      <span class="firstName">Steve</span>
    </td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>Male</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="profileImage badge-avatar badge-green"></span>
      <span class="firstName">Yuvan</span>
    </td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>Male</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a php function if you are interested :

```html
 function randomHex() {
  $chars = '77B5FE';//ABCDEF0123456789
  $color = '#';
  for ( $i = 0; $i < 6; $i++ ) {
    $color .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
  }
  return $color;
}

<div  class="u-img">
  <h1 style="background-color:<?php echo randomHex() ?>;border-radius:100px;width:50px;height:50px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;">
  <?php echo strtoupper($first_letter) ?>
 </h1>
</div>
```

I think it will have to be changed a little.

Comment: but a jquery solution would be much helpful. Anyways thank you for the effort.

Comment: The same function in JS : `function getRandomColor() {
  var length = 6;
  var chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var hex = '#';
  while(length--) hex += chars[(Math.random() * 16) | 0];
  return hex;
}

document.write(getRandomColor());`